# C++ to Csharp structure

Tags: c#, c++

I am a beginner in c# and I have to convert a c++ structure to c# in order to use a specific DLL function.

Here is the C++ function header:

```
CYWINEXPORT CY_RETURN_STATUS CyGetDeviceInfoVidPid (  
CY_VID_PID vidPid,                          /*VID and PID of device of interest*/
UINT8 *deviceIdList,                        /*Array of device ID's returned*/    
CY_DEVICE_INFO *deviceInfoList,             /*Array of pointers to device info list*/
UINT8 *deviceCount,                         /*Count of devices with specified VID PID*/ 
UINT8 infoListLength                        /*Total length of the deviceInfoList allocated
                                             (Size of deviceInfoList array)*/   
);
```

Here are the C++ structures needed:

```
typedef struct _CY_DEVICE_INFO {
CY_VID_PID vidPid;                                      /*VID and PID*/
UCHAR numInterfaces;                                    /*Number of interfaces supported*/
UCHAR manufacturerName [CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];     /*Manufacturer name*/
UCHAR productName [CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];          /*Product name*/
UCHAR serialNum [CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];            /*Serial number*/
UCHAR deviceFriendlyName [CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];   /*Device friendly name : Windows only*/
CY_DEVICE_TYPE deviceType [CY_MAX_DEVICE_INTERFACE];    /*Type of the device each interface has(Valid only 
                                                        for USB Serial Device) and interface in vendor class*/
CY_DEVICE_CLASS deviceClass [CY_MAX_DEVICE_INTERFACE];  /*Interface class of each interface*/

CY_DEVICE_SERIAL_BLOCK  deviceBlock; /* On Windows, each USB Serial device interface is associated with a
                                        separate driver instance. This variable represents the present driver
                                        interface instance that is associated with a serial block. */
} CY_DEVICE_INFO,*PCY_DEVICE_INFO;



typedef struct _CY_VID_PID {
UINT16 vid;         /*Holds the VID of the device*/
UINT16 pid;         /*Holds the PID of the device*/
} CY_VID_PID, *PCY_VID_PID;
```

And here is how I initialize my structure and how I call my function:

```
cyReturnStatus = CyGetDeviceInfoVidPid (cyVidPid, deviceID, (PCY_DEVICE_INFO)&cyDeviceInfoList, &cyNumDevices, 16);
```

I tried to write the equivalent code in C#.

Here is my function header:

```
[DllImport("cyusbserial.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public unsafe static extern enum_CY_Return_Status CyGetDeviceInfoVidPid(
            Struct_CY_VID_PID vidPid,                   //VID and PID of device of interest
            byte[] deviceIdList,                         //Array of device ID's returned
            Struct_CY_DEVICE_INFO[] deviceInfoList, //Array of pointers to device info list
            byte* deviceCount,                          //Count of devices with specified VID PID
            byte infoListLength                         //Total length of the deviceInfoList allocated
                                                        (Size of deviceInfoList array)
        );
```

Here are my C# structures:

```
public struct Struct_CY_VID_PID
        {
            public ushort vid;     //Holds the VID of the device
            public ushort pid;     //Holds the PID of the device
        }

 public struct Struct_CY_DEVICE_INFO
        {
            public Struct_CY_VID_PID vidPid;
            public byte numInterfaces;
            public byte[] manufacturerName;
            public byte[] productName;          //Product name
            public byte[] serialNum;            //Serial number
            public byte[] deviceFriendlyName;   //Device friendly name : Windows only
            public enum_CY_DEVICE_TYPE[] deviceType;    //Type of the device each interface has(Valid only 
                                                            //for USB Serial Device) and interface in vendor class
            public enum_CY_DEVICE_CLASS[] deviceClass;  //Interface class of each interface

            public enum_CY_DEVICE_SERIAL_BLOCK deviceBlock; // On Windows, each USB Serial device interface is associated with a
                                            separate driver instance. This variable represents the present driver
                                            interface instance that is associated with a serial block. 
        }
```

And here is how I initialize my structure and how I call my function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                DeviceInfoList[i].manufacturerName = new byte[CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];
                DeviceInfoList[i].productName = new byte[CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];
                DeviceInfoList[i].serialNum = new byte[CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];
                DeviceInfoList[i].deviceFriendlyName = new byte[CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE];
                DeviceInfoList[i].deviceType = new C_USBtoUART.enum_CY_DEVICE_TYPE[CY_MAX_DEVICE_INTERFACE];
                DeviceInfoList[i].deviceClass = new C_USBtoUART.enum_CY_DEVICE_CLASS[CY_MAX_DEVICE_INTERFACE];
            }

fixed (byte* pDevice_Count = &Device_Count)
            {
                Return_Status_1 = C_USBtoUART.CyGetDeviceInfoVidPid(VIDPID, DeviceID,DeviceInfoList, pDevice_Count, 16);
            }
```

I think my error come from how I send "DeviceInfoList". I tried to use "ref" for it but it did not work better.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A string in c++ is terminated with a '\0'.  So your code is allowing enough space for the maximum size of the string.  Your c#  structure isn't allowing the same size.  So add attribute above each byte[] : [MarshalAs(byte,SizeConst = CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE)]

Comment: @jdweng that code is invalid. The inline arrays in the struct should by UnmanagedType.ByValTStr if they really are C strings and null terminated. Although UCHAR sounds more like binary data so UnmanagedType.ByValArray would be correct there.

Comment: David : You are wrong again.  The same max size CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE that c++ is using MUST be included in the structure size in c#.  Then ByValToStr will still work if the actual size of the byte[] is smaller and terminated with '\0'

Comment: @jdweng Let your pride go for a minute and try to compile your code. It does not compile. Whether or not ByValTStr or ByValArray is correct depends on whether or not the data is null terminated. But first and foremost your code does not compile. Or do you dispute that?

Comment: OK.  I should of been :         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = CY_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_SIZE)]

Comment: @jdweng That won't compile either. Have you ever written a pinvoke?